# Store mongoDB document data as a variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, socket.io

I have a node.js app where I want to send data from mongoDB over socket.io where I can have the data display on a client but I can't figure out how to send it over the socket, the code is as follow

```
MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/", function (err, db) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var dbo = db.db("database1");
    dbo.collection("items").find({
        iname: search,
        qty: qValue
    }, {
        _id: 0
    }).toArray(function (err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        if ({ $eq: "yesView"}) {
            console.log("Find Succsessful;");
                if ({ $eq: "notRec"}) {
                    socket.emit('findSuccess', (result[2]), (result[3]))
                }
```

But on the client when i have

```
socket.on('findSuccess', function (view, rec) { 
    viewVal = view;
    recVal = rec;
});
```

both viewVal and recVal are equal to null and when I do `console.log(result);` if i put in cd for the search and 4 for the qValue it has

> [ { iname: 'cd',
>
> qty: '4',
>
> view: 'yesView',
>
> rec: 'notRec' } ]

My question how do i get viewVal on client to equal what view is in the document?

Comment: try to change result[2] to result[0].view

Comment: That worked, that was really simple, thank you! @gaetanoM is there a way I can + rep you or anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @gaetanoM said, it works if you change `result[2]` to `result[0].view`, I'm only answering this because I don't want to leave it unanswered.